# Is there a free service for echoing back POST-ed or GET-ed data?

Tags: forms

I'm designing a programming exercise where students need to construct an HTML form.

They are not ready for building the form receiver themselves, but it would be nice, if they could put something meaningful to `form`'s `action` attribute.

Do you know a web service, which just lists the data that was sent to it (either by GET or POST)?

Comment: Found a service myself.

Comment: Questions asking for [recommendations for sites and resources](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is expressly prohibited on this site as they often attract spam and self-promotional responses. Please see [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) link for more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php. In order to make it work your students would need to set the action parameter to that URL and the method to `POST`. When they submit their forms the utility will display the posted data in a raw format.